# Better implementation of reverse sign in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm interested in better implementation of "reverse sign" function in Bash. I know I can do something like:

```
"$(($1 * -1))"
```

But this produces a positive number w/o sign, but I need signed return value:

```
"$((-1 * -1))" == 1 # but I need '+1'
```

My current version is:

```
# Reverts the +/- operators for an integer argument.
#
#   $ polarize -1   # +1
#   $ polarize +12  # -12
#   $ polarize 2-2  # 2-2
#   $ polarize - 1  # - 1
#
function polarize() {
  [ $# -eq 0 ] && return

  if [[ "$@" =~ ^-([[:digit:]]+)$ ]]; then
    echo -n "+${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  elif [[ "$@" =~ ^\+([[:digit:]]+)$ ]]; then
    echo -n "-${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  else
    echo -n "$@"
  fi
}
```

Some notes:

- Function should handle only signed integers (i.e. `-1`, `+22`, but not `0` or `100`)
- Function shouldn't return anything if there is no argument
- Function should correct handle multiple arguments (don't do anything)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `printf`:

```
printf '%+d\n' "$(( -$n ))"
```

The `printf` format string `%+d` means "print the given argument as a decimal integer, with a sign".

So you'll get something like

```bash
revsign () {
    if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [[ $1 =~ ^[+-][[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
        printf '%+d\n' "$(( -$1 ))"
    fi
}
```

This does not do anything when given multiple arguments or when given a single argument that is not a signed integer.

To pass through the arguments when there are multiple of them or when the single argument isn't an integer with a sign:

```bash
revsign () {
    if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [[ $1 =~ ^[+-][[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
        printf '%+d\n' "$(( -$1 ))"
    elif [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$@"
    fi
}
```

If you want to be careful and not accept octal numbers (written with a leading `0`, as in `034`) as valid integers, change the regular expression to

```
^[+-][1-9][[:digit:]]*$
```

Comment: @Isaac Fixed now. I was thinking in terms of `int` and `unsigned int` (for unknown reasons), but the user's list makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a regex, you may as well make it better.

A simple `^-([[:digit:]]+)$` will only capture the digits, not the sign, and:

- To capture either sign, just change the regex to:

  ```
  ^([+-])([0-9]+)$
  ```

  Note that the sign (`+` or `-`) is **not** optional (?), it must exist (as per your requirements).
- Not remove leading zeros as in 008 that will raise the error:

  > 008: invalid octal number

  Change to:

  ```
  ^([+-])0*([0-9]+)$
  ```
- It is not clear from your description if spaces and/or tabs could be allowed, it they are, change to:

  ```
  ^[[:blank:]]*([+-])0*([0-9]+)$
  ```

Then, the correct number could be re-constructed from:

```
${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

Or, simply:

```
${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1:2}
```

The whole script would become something like:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Reverts the +/- operators for an integer argument.
#
#   $ polarize -1   # +1
#   $ polarize +12  # -12
#   $ polarize 2-2  # 2-2
#   $ polarize - 1  # - 1
#
polarize () {
    re='^[[:blank:]]*([+-])0*([[:digit:]]+)$'

    [[ $# -ne 1  ]] && return
    [[ $1 =~ $re ]] || return

    printf '<%+d>' "$(( -${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1:2} ))"
}

for n; do
    printf '%s' "testing ==$n=="
    polarize "$n"
    echo
done
```

And when executed (the list of values is valid for the whole script just for testing sake, the function accepts only one argument) (no output for 0, 100, and some other tests):

```
$ ./testbash.sh +1 -1 +22 -12 0 100 2-2 "- 1" +008
testing ==+1==<-1>
testing ==-1==<+1>
testing ==+22==<-22>
testing ==-12==<+12>
testing ==0==
testing ==100==
testing ==2-2==
testing ==- 1==
testing ==+008==<-8>
```